# How to access object's properties which are not defined

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to access an object's properties which are not predefined in the class.

My code scans for Bluetooth devices. I need to connect to a BLE device using MAC address.

This information is under `e.Device.BluetoothDevice.Address` but I can access this data only during runtime. When code is not running I can not see `BluetoothDevice`.

[image]

[image]

What is the correct way to retrieve this data?

Comment: Access something that does not exist? It´s pretty unclear what "properties" you refer to. What exactly do you want to achieve? What did you try already and how did it fail your expactations?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Looks like `IDevice` does not have a `BluetoothDevice` property, but the actual object does. Since you can't instantiate an interface in C#, the actual runtime type of the object is necessarily not `IDevice`. trixo needs to cast `e.Device` to the actual runtime type. With any luck, `WhateverType.BluetoothDevice` will be public, not protected.

Comment: @EdPlunkett exactly, Is there a way how to get to this data ?

Comment: @trixo Based on what you've got in your watch window screenshot about the actual type of `e.Device`, I think Joachim Haglund's answer has a good chance of being correct. His answer is the first thing I would try (whoops, and his updated answer is the *second* thing I would try).

Comment: Try `typeof(e.Device)` and whatever you get, go to the base class and up the inheritance tree as long as you find `Address` defined. Then use that upper most class to cast to. This way you're relatively sure that whatever `IDevice` you get you're not presuming something that is not there... I say so because you have just an interface (`IDevice`) because the API is designed to switch the actual type underneath based on circumstances unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to cast "e" to the correct class.

```
var test = (Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.EventArgs.DeviceEventArgs)e;
```

then it should have all the correct properties and methods exposed.

edit: jsut saw on your screenshot that it was IDevice that was causing the issues so try casting e.Device:

```
var test = (Plugin.BLE.Android.Device) e.Device
```

Comment: depending on the implementations this cast should probably be contained in a try-catch aswell, sence the IDevice type implies that e.Device could be of a diffrent type, in which case the cast would crash.

Comment: To this, I would add pid's thoughtful suggestion that the actual runtime type of e.Device can't be relied on to be the same always and forever, so there should be some checking.

Comment: Don´tr rely on exceptions, in particular if those exceptions represent normal - expectable - behaviour. Having said this instead of letting the cast crash, why not use an `as`-cast and see if it returns `null`?